# I Have No IPTables

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

I have something really weird going on that I can't seem to find any reference to after a lot of googling. I seem to have *no* iptables. Not that the chains are flushed or that they are all ACCEPT rules or something, the tables themselves don't seem to exist. Here is what I mean:

The story is, my docker stopped working at some point in the last few months and I finally got around to fixing it. The error was being caused by the following command:

```
$ iptables -A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

Which docker runs as part of its startup and which I tried to run manually to debug.

So then I started messing around trying to add different chains and rules in different places, and everything was giving that error. So finally I tried to just list everything

```
$sudo iptables -S 
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
$ sudo iptables -L
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
$ sudo iptables --list
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

nothing. So I tried to look at each of the tables

```
# iptables -vL -t filter
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
# iptables -vL -t nat
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
# iptables -vL -t mangle
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
# iptables -vL -t raw
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
# iptables -vL -t security
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

More nothing, it's like the actual tables themselves are gone. Even something as simple as

```
# iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables: Bad built-in chain name.
```

doesn't work.

Has anyone seen this before? Is there any way to get the tables back?

My system is Ubuntu 18.10 with Kernel 5.1.8

### Updates

I have since added all the iptables modules to my `/etc/modules` and rebuilt the initramfs. The modules are now loaded on boot but it didn't solve the problem.

I found that the `iptables-save` command does not error, but it also only prints the following:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Tue Jun 11 17:35:52 2019
*nat
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jun 11 17:35:52 2019
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Tue Jun 11 17:35:52 2019
*mangle
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jun 11 17:35:52 2019
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Tue Jun 11 17:35:52 2019
*raw
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jun 11 17:35:52 2019
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Tue Jun 11 17:35:52 2019
*security
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jun 11 17:35:52 2019
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Tue Jun 11 17:35:52 2019
*filter
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jun 11 17:35:52 2019
```

I also found that ip6tables appears to be working normally, its only iptables that is broken.

Next I tried running some of the iptables commands in verbose mode.

```
# iptables -S -vv 
libiptc vlibxtables.so.12. 0 bytes.
Table `filter'
Hooks: pre/in/fwd/out/post = 7f68/9f6085dd/5616/9f60a8e0/5616
Underflows: pre/in/fwd/out/post = 36e4540/7fff/36e48e8/7fff/0
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

```
# iptables -N  DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -vv
```

In verbose mode this commant doesn't complete, the output is huge. I tried dumping it to a file but I killed it when that file reached 8.5GB in size. The output is all repitions of the following pattern:

```
libiptc vlibxtables.so.12. 1032595540 bytes.
Table `filter'
Hooks: pre/in/fwd/out/post = 7ffe/92c0b5dd/55a7/92c0d8e0/55a7
Underflows: pre/in/fwd/out/post = 3d8c10f0/7ffe/3d8c1498/7ffe/3d8c2854
Entry 0 (0):
SRC IP: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
DST IP: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
Interface: `'/................to `'/................
Protocol: 0
Flags: 00
Invflags: 00
Counters: 0 packets, 0 bytes
Cache: 00000000
Target name: `' [0]
verdict=0

Entry 0 (0):
SRC IP: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
DST IP: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
Interface: `'/................to `'/................
Protocol: 0
Flags: 00
Invflags: 00
Counters: 0 packets, 0 bytes
Cache: 00000000
Target name: `' [0]
verdict=0
```

Hopefully this makes sense to someone, it's meaningless to me.

Comment: What happens if you reboot? Does your kernel have `ip_tables` built-in or as a module? If it is a module, does `lsmod` show it is present?

Comment: Good call, they're modules and they weren't loaded automatically. I `modprobe`d `ip_tables` as well as the all the table modules (`iptables_filter`, etc) but I still have the same errors

Comment: It's *really* strange those modules don't get loaded automatically. Did you reboot? Any error messages in `dmesg` after reboot?

Comment: Yes I rebooted and also upgraded to kernel 5.1.8, nothing unusual in dmesg

Comment: @dirkt I updated the post with some more information I collected, maybe you can make sense of it, I couldn't

Comment: What the command `iptables` does is to communicate with the kernel, and it looks like this communication goes wrong, because something in the kernel is not working as expected. In particular, normally the required modules would autoload. You do use a stock kernel, a normal Ubuntu system, no custom security restrictions etc.? Nothing funny in the kernel module management? Just in case: Is the package that contains the `iptables` command current and matches the kernel? (Though i"ve never seen difficulties in this respect before).

Comment: I actually do use a custom kernel, but the config is (supposed to be) copied from the mainline ubuntu config, and it just adds ACS override for pcie devices so it shouldn't be causing a problem. Just in case, the config is [here](https://gitlab.com/Queuecumber/linux-acs-override/blob/master/workspaces/5.1/kernel_config). Can I build just the iptables binary from source or does it come with the kernel?

Comment: Tried building latest iptables binaries from the source and that also has the same error message

Comment: Try to fix it by reinstalling the docker-engine: `apt-get remove docker-engine` followed by `apt-get install docker-engine`.

Comment: @harrymc I tried many times, it's not a docker problem, docker fails because it cant make it's iptables rules because iptables is broken

Comment: Are you using the latest docker version? You are using DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1, but it [seems](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/12294#issuecomment-432921518) that the namespace is now DOCKER. An example iptables save is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29980145/165358). (I'm trying to help but I'm not using docker.)

Comment: I tried  the restore command from your second link just in case but it has the same error. It isn't a docker problem it's an iptables problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a kernel config problem. Usually when I apply my patch a build a new kernel, I copy the config I was using from the previous version (in hindsight maybe a bad idea). Once I merged my config with the latest Ubuntu kernel config and rebuilt the kernel, my iptables output looked normal again.

Answer (score 2):

Searching on internet i found that is possible to restore iptables on Linux using the following command

## iptables-restore < /root/working.iptables.rules

However there are some technical guides which suggest that if using kubernetes proxy iptables rules lost after restarting iptables+node.

The following files provides useful information about it:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-save-restore-iptables-firewall-config-ubuntu/

https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/1922

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/iptables-no-chain-tarjet-match-by-that-name-941406/

I hope that can help!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, unfortunately the restore command would have required I saved the rules using `iptables-save` (creating the file `/root/working.iptables.rules`) when they were still working. The other suggestions unfortunately also had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried manually reinstalling iptables?

```
./configure --prefix=/usr      \
            --sbindir=/sbin    \
            --disable-nftables \
            --enable-libipq    \
            --with-xtlibdir=/lib/xtables &&
make
make install &&
ln -sfv ../../sbin/xtables-legacy-multi /usr/bin/iptables-xml &&

for file in ip4tc ip6tc ipq iptc xtables
do
  mv -v /usr/lib/lib${file}.so.* /lib &&
  ln -sfv ../../lib/$(readlink /usr/lib/lib${file}.so) /usr/lib/lib${file}.so
done
make install-iptables
```

Drawn from [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/iptables.html).

Comment: yes I tried using built-from-source iptables and it gives the same errors

Comment: okay well honestly I don't have anything left to recommend to you than a new clean install